# How convert a local csv file to spark data frame on jupyter server?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, hdfs

My CSV file is inside my directory at jupyter server. I am getting error whenever i am trying to load it in my notebook as `spark dataframe` using `spark.read.csv`.

The error I am getting is :

```
AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist.
```

`spark.read.csv` is expecting the location of my file to be at `hdfs` while it is inside my jupyter directory. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

For copying the files from local to hdfs, Try this

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /local/path/to/file.csv
```

Or

```
hdfs dfs -put /local/path/to/file.csv  /user/hadoop/hadoopdir
```